# Creating a filter in an express js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Sample json:

```
var jsonString = '[{"name":"Manchester GTUG","meetup":"First Monday of every month","tags":["gtug","google","manchester","madlab"]},{"name":"Manchester jQuery Group","meetup":"First Tuesday of every month","tags":["jquery","javascript","jresig","madlab"]},{"name":"Hybrid!","meetup":"First Monday of every month","tags":["jquery","javascript","jresig","madlab"]}]';
```

So i have my express js routes:

```
var list = require('./data');
var jsonData = require('../public/data/items.json');
var itemList = list.items;

exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {list: itemList});
};

exports.get('/items.json', function(req, res){
    res.json(jsonData);
});
```

What I'd like to do like below.

1. Get my json file via url.
2. Able to filter the amounts like so...

> localhost:8000/items/?start=1&end=8 **OR** localhost:8000/items.json/?start=1&end=8

#### How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Node Server side or client side ?

Comment: @Venkatraman server side i suppose as to not bog down client side

Comment: share the json response to understand to structure to help you in filter

Comment: use https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: @Venkatraman added example json

Comment: i dont see any amounts to filter. only has name, meetup, tags

Comment: @Venkatraman the amount of items shown. if theres a list of 50+ items. id like to be able to get items 1 to 27

Comment: Your json string is not valid one jsonString. it should be enclosed in object with property like var jsonData = { "list": [{}, {}, {}] }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101794/discussion-between-modelesq-and-venkatraman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below in Express Router. You have to filter in your code. there is no predefined option to filter through URL.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jsonData = require('../public/data/items.json');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var itemList = {};
  itemList['data'] = jsonData.data.slice(0, 27)
  res.json(itemList);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Reference Slice:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice